# Does Creating a New Thread Duplicate File Descriptors and Socket Descriptors in Linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets

Everyone knows the classic model of a process listening for connections on a socket and forking a new process to handle each new connection.  Normal practice is for the parent process to immediately call `close` on the newly created socket, decrementing the handle count so that only the child has a handle to the new socket.

I've read that the **only difference** between a process and a thread in Linux is that threads share the same memory.  In this case I'm assuming spawning a new thread to handle a new connection also duplicates file descriptors and would also require the 'parent' thread to close it's copy of the socket?

Comment: "*I've read that the only difference between a process and a thread in Linux is that threads share the same memory.*" There are lots of other differences between processes and threads. For example, processes can contain more than one thread.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Threads share the same memory, so they share the same variables. If you close socket in parent thread, it will be also closed in child thread.

EDIT:

- man fork: The  child  inherits *copies* of the parent’s set of open file descriptors.
- man pthreads: threads *share* a range of other attributes (i.e., these attributes are process-wide rather than per-thread): [...] open file descriptors

And some code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// global variable
int fd = -1;

void * threadProc(void * param) {
    cout << "thread: begin" << endl;
    sleep(2);
    int rc = close(fd);
    if (rc == -1) {
        int errsv = errno;
        cout << "thread: close() failed: " << strerror(errsv) << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "thread: file is closed" << endl;
    }
    cout << "thread: end" << endl;
}

int main() {
    int rc = open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY);
    fd = rc;

    pthread_t threadId;
    rc = pthread_create(&threadId, NULL, &threadProc, NULL);

    sleep(1);

    rc = close(fd);
    if (rc == -1) {
        int errsv = errno;
        cout << "main: close() failed: " << strerror(errsv) << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        cout << "main: file is closed" << endl;
    }

    sleep(2);
}
```

Output is:

```
thread: begin
main: file is closed
thread: close() failed: Bad file descriptor
thread: end
```

Comment: I don't have it with me here at work, but I can check my copy of Stevens' UNPv2 once I get home.

Comment: @Shelby - Thanks, I have a copy of UNP but have only gotten to read about a third of it.

Comment: It looks like, from the beginning of this answer, that it is based on a wrong assumption that file descriptors are akin to local variables.

Answer (score 11):

In principle, Linux clone() can implement not only a new process (like fork()), or a new thread (like pthread_create perhaps), but also anything in between.

In practice, it is only ever used for one or the other. Threads created with pthread_create share the file descriptors with all other threads in the process (not just the parent). This is non-negotiable.

Sharing a file descriptor and having a copy is different. If you have a copy (like fork()) then all copies must be closed before the file handle goes away. If you share the FD in a thread, once one closes it, it's gone.

Answer (score 9):

On Linux threads are implemented via the [clone](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) syscall using the CLONE_FILES flag:

> If CLONE_FILES is set, the calling
>   process and the child processes share
>   the same file descriptor table. Any
>   file descriptor created by the calling
>   process or by the child process is
>   also valid in the other process.
>   Similarly, if one of the processes
>   closes a file descriptor, or changes
>   its associated flags (using the
>   fcntl(2) F_SETFD operation), the other
>   process is also affected.

Also have a look at the glibc source code for the details of how it is used in [createthread.c](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=nptl/sysdeps/pthread/createthread.c;hb=HEAD):

```
  int clone_flags = (CLONE_VM | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGNAL
             | CLONE_SETTLS | CLONE_PARENT_SETTID
             | CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID | CLONE_SYSVSEM
#if __ASSUME_NO_CLONE_DETACHED == 0
             | CLONE_DETACHED
#endif
             | 0);
```